# get token from endpoint in angular2

Tags: api, http, angular

The endpoint of my API it's on "localhost/get_token" but I don't know how to bind it to a variable on my Angular2 service 
I've tried this:

```
let token = () => { return this._http.get('localhost/endpoint')}
```

I'm not sure how to make the get call

This is the endpoint on my server.js

```
app.get('/get_token', function(req,res) {
res.send({
'access_token':accessToken
    });
});
```

Comment: I think you should check out this link https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/server-communication.html

Answer (score 0):

Normally you post user login and password to the server to get a token. I suppose that you're just testing. If that's the case try something like this :

```
let token:string;

getToken() { 
   return this._http.get('localhost/endpoint') //I think that url must match your server endpoint something like localhost/get_token
      .map((response: Response) => {
         let data = response.json()

         if(data.access_token)
           this.token = data.access_token //get your token here
      })
}
```